# Setting Public variables in VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating public variables in my program to be used across multiple subs in the module.

```
Public c As Range, wsSrc As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet, cDest As Range
```

However I want these variables to have the following value across the entire function as well

```
Set wsSrc = Workbooks("SourceBook").Worksheets("SourceSheet") 
Set wsDest = Workbooks("DestBook").Worksheets("DestSheet")
```

Is there a way for me to set these and their values carry across the entire function?
Also for c and cDest I am changing those in the functions so I **Do Not** want those defined globally. Only **wsSRC** and **wsDest**. Are variables in VBA immutable?

Comment: So you want to avoid the proper mechanism of passing variables to subs (arguments) and use global variables instead, but you want them to behave like arguments?

Comment: Set up a public function, the function returns the value of the variable, but if the  variable is Nothing, then it sets the variable to your default value before returning it.

Answer (score 2):

This is a question of scope. For using variables across a module, you don't need to set them public - `Public` is used for making variables available to other modules.

In this case just need to declare variables outside function

```
'Module begining
Dim  wsSrc As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet

Function f1
    Dim c As Range, cDest As Range
    '... wsSrc and wsDest are acessible, eg:
    Set c = wsSrc.Columns(2).Find(What:="Commercial Income", LookIn:=xlValues, _ LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)
End Function

Function f2
    '... wsSrc and wsDest are also acessible here
End Function
```

However, to avoid initialization problems, you may use them as properties, so each time they are called, value is properly returned:

```
'Module begining
Property Get wsSrc As Worksheet
    Set wsSrc = Workbooks("SourceBook").Worksheets("SourceSheet") 
End Property

Property Get wsSrc As Worksheet
    Set wsDest = Workbooks("DestBook").Worksheets("DestSheet")
End Property

Function f1
    Dim c As Range, cDest As Range
    '... wsSrc and wsDest are acessible
End Function

Function f2
    '... wsSrc and wsDest are also acessible here
End Function
```

Comment: Would these also be accessible in the subs of functions? How would I call then to be used Currently am Calling it using /// Set c = wsSrc.Columns(2).Find(What:="Commercial Income", LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                  LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False) ///
    Where wsSrc is initialized using Dim. How would this change.

Comment: Because variables are declared outside functions/subs, are available to them. Just call them inside functions, variables are available.